# On back pressed goes to login screen after register

Tags: java, android, authentication

I made an app that requires the user to register. The first time user opens the app - login screen opens. They need to click on the "go to register" button to go to register activity. After they register, they are automatically logged in.

Now here is the issue - when the user first registers he is sent to MainActivity. He should press back and the app should close. But when he tries to exit the app he presses the back button and instead of app closing it goes back to login screen.
The next time I try to sign in, I have no problem - it goes straight to the MainActivity.

This is how my activities look like:

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_REGISTER = 0;

@InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
@InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
@InjectView(R.id.link_register) TextView _registerLink;

CheckBox checkBoxShowPassword;

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = _emailText.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = _passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                // login user
                login(email, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    //        Go to register screen
    _registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start the Register activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REGISTER);
        }
    });

    //        Password checkbox
    checkBoxShowPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxShowPassword);
    checkBoxShowPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
            if (!isChecked) {
                // show password
                _passwordText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            } else {
                // hide password
                _passwordText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });
}

//    Login
public void login(final String email, final String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Login");

    if (!validate()) {
        onLoginFailed();
        return;
    }

    //        Change to false for disabling after error
    _loginButton.setEnabled(true);

    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
    progressDialog.show();

    // TODO: Implementing authentication logic

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Registration failed due to connectivity issues", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
    //                _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // disable going back to the MainActivity
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

public void onLoginSuccess() {
    _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    finish();
}

public void onLoginFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
}

//    Validation
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        _emailText.setError("Enter a valid email address");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _emailText.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 20) {
        _passwordText.setError("Enter between 4 and 20 alphanumeric characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _passwordText.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
}
```

RegisterActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

@InjectView(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
@InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
@InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_register) Button _registerButton;
@InjectView(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;

CheckBox checkBoxShowPassword;

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //        Register button
    _registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = _nameText.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = _emailText.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = _passwordText.getText().toString().trim();
            String phone = getMyPhoneNumber();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                register(name, email, password, phone);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    //        Go to login screen
    _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
            finish();
        }
    });

    //        Password checkbox
    checkBoxShowPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxShowPassword);
    checkBoxShowPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
            if (!isChecked) {
                // show password
                _passwordText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            } else {
                // hide password
                _passwordText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });
}

   //    Register
public void register(final String name, final String email, final String password, final String phone) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Register");

    if (!validate()) {
        onRegisterFailed();
        return;
    }

    _registerButton.setEnabled(false);

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
    progressDialog.show();

    // TODO: Implementing register logic
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    //TODO: insert contacts to local db
                    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    };

                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        if (phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER) != -1)
                        {
                            String username = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            db.addContact(username, phoneNumber);
                        }
                    }
                    phones.close();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //                        Auto login
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Registration failed due to connectivity issues", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            _registerButton.setEnabled(true);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("phone", phone);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}

public void onRegisterSuccess() {
    _registerButton.setEnabled(true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();
}

public void onRegisterFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    _registerButton.setEnabled(true);
}

    //    Validation
public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
        _nameText.setError("Enter at least 3 characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _nameText.setError(null);
    }

    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        _emailText.setError("Enter a valid email address");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _emailText.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 20) {
        _passwordText.setError("Enter between 4 and 20 alphanumeric characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _passwordText.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}

// Get users phone number
private String getMyPhoneNumber() {
    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String MyPhoneNumber = "0000000000";

    try
    {
        MyPhoneNumber =tMgr.getLine1Number();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex)
    {
    }

    if(MyPhoneNumber.equals("")){
        MyPhoneNumber = tMgr.getSubscriberId();
    }

    return MyPhoneNumber;
}

private String getMy10DigitPhoneNumber() {
    String s = getMyPhoneNumber();
    return s.substring(2);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain this sentence in more details: "when the user presses the back button they are sent back to login screen instead of app shutting down."

Comment: finish the register Activity while proceeding using `finish()`

Comment: @SohailZahid I tried this but I got the same problem.

Comment: is there any specific purpose that you are using startActivityForResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my idea you just do one thing that when you are passing from login activity to register_activity just finish the login_activity like this

```
    //        Go to register screen
        _registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Register activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REGISTER);
                LoginActivity.this.finish(); 
            }
        });
```

If you still facing the same problem then when you are opens the login_activity first then create a variable of that class and assign the value to that variable like this

```
    public static LoginActivity mLogin_activity;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mLogin_activity=LoginActivity.this;
```

Then check this value is null or not in `onBackPressed()` method in `Main_Activity` if that value is null then finish that main_activity otherwise finish that login_activity too; Something like this:

```
  @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if (LoginActivity.mLogin_activity!=null) {
                LoginActivity.mLogin_activity.finish();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }else {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
```

Hope i had answered your question...

Comment: I first tried adding LoginActivity.this.finish(); , but when the user tried to log in without internet connection and then tried to press the back button he was able to open the mainActivity instead of closing the app. Then I tried doing this but I got the following error: public static LoginActivity mLogin_activity=LoginActivity.this; Cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: sorry for the late response but do one thing in your login_activity put the override method onBackPressed(){} and finish the class you want to finish then it will work. i think.. and check your manifesto.xml also which class you opens first.

Comment: Than you for your response. I was thinking of doing override onbackpressed in register activity, but I am afraid it will disable user to go back to login if he doesn't want to register :) I didn't have the time to try this yet, but I will hopefully give it a go this weekend.
The first activity the app opens is login activity, which has a button to go to register activity.

Answer (score 1):

when you write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REGISTER);
```

This must need to override onActivityResult method to handle that result.

In that code you just write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I hope this could be help you.

Comment: Tried that but I get the same problem - it goes back to login screen.

Comment: try to this Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

Comment: Panavala I have a different problem now - when I try to register (i was testing without internet connection for bugs) I get my custom message that there is no internet connection. That is good, but when i try to press back button to close the app then the main activity opens.

Comment: Update your code and you should maintain your session.isLoggedIn() in RegisterActivity. If no intenet connection then you put session.setLogin(false);

Comment: I tried to put session.setLogin(false); in 
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {... and in public void onRegisterFailed() {... in RegisterActivity, but it also did not work

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found out that I was calling a variable from another activity which was on my Register.xml  (the progressbarBtn) instead of the progressbar that I inserted on Login.Java which was ProgressbarBtn3

thats why it is taking me back to the register page